# Is it possible to use dropbox js sync api with "Offline Web Applications" to load initial state of the app?

Tags: html, dropbox-api, offlineapps

For example: If one creates a "offline html5 web app", say todo app, where all the app's data needs to be available at application launch time.

And at application launch there might not be any internet connection, does dropbox sync api make app data available offline?

Or do I have to write some sort of sync mechanism between offline storage and dropbox data store. (This approach seems to beat the purpose of having a sync api)

Answer (score 1):

The Sync API only has libraries for iOS, OS X, and Android, so it's hard to tell which API you're talking about here. The JavaScript library supports the Core API (files) and the Datastore API (structured data), neither of which persists state offline between runs of the app.